# PHP Delete files in directory if the name is in provided list

Tags: php

I am completely new in PHP and I am trying to achieve simple goal and I need your help please.

I would like to write a script that would take an array of values and delete all the files from the parent folder.

So basically loop in array of file names, and for each name from the array try to find file with same name and if found -> delete it.

So far I achieved to get list of files from the parent folder by using $files = scandir('../');
I cannot find a syntax that would take a list of names and then loop through the $files and deletes everything that match the name from the provided list.

Example:

array ('1.jpg', '2.jpg') -> List of file names that I need to delete
$files = scandir('../') -> List of actual files in the parent folder

action -> 'deleted file '1.jpg' and '2.jpg' from the parent folder

I hope that it is understandable what I am trying to achieve :D

Thanks a lot!

I was able to delete one file in the parent folder using "hardcoded" name

```
<?php
$path = '../config.php';
if (!unlink($path)) {
    echo 'File not deleted';
} else {
    echo 'File' . $path . ' deleted successfuly!';
}
```

I also tried to get a list of all files in the parent folder using

```
<?php
$files = scandir('../');
var_dump($files);
```

Comment: please add `scandir()` code too

Comment: Loop over your scandir result, and use `in_array` to check if the current file name you are processing is contained in your array of file names that need to be deleted. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Agreed with @CBroe

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906858/4248328 (only !in_array needs to be in_array)

Comment: thanks a lot guys! I have made some progress.